# How to test if array item's text contains a substring?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I've been doing research on testing if a value exists in an array, and keep getting matches for indexOf('textvalue').

But, my 'textvalue' will be a substring, and therefore won't pull a match.  This is because I'm passing the field name to the method, and just need to delete the "Door: Front Left;" text by matching the array item on "Door". Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Here's the example code I'm working on:

(spnSelectedDisclosures will have a list of selected fields, and this is the code to remove the previous field selection from the text, which is semi-colon delimited.)

```
var currentText = $("#spnSelectedDisclosures").text();

var existingArr = currentText.split(";")

for (i=0;i < existingArr.length;i++) {

   var indexItem = " " + existingArr[i].toString(); // why is this still an object, instead of a string? Adding a space to it was a desperate try to make indexItem a string variable.

    if (indexItem.contains(substringText)) { // offending line, saying the object has no method 'contains'
       alert("there's been a match at: " + i);
       textToRemoveIndex = i;
       break;
    }
  }

 var textToRemove = existingArr[textToRemoveIndex];
 var newText = currentText.replace(textToRemove,""); 
 $("#spnSelectedDisclosures").text(newText);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's about this?

```
for (i=0;i < existingArr.length;i++) {
  if (existingArr[i].indexOf(substringText) > -1) { 
    alert("there's been a match at: " + i);
    textToRemoveIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok.  I was going about it in a direct way.  This makes sense, too.  Just have to look for index to be a positive number, and that essentially means "contains".  Thanks, guys!  Also, thanks for the compatibility mention regarding the .contains().

Answer (score 0):

[String.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) has very limited support:

> **Browser compatibility**
>
> ```
> Chrome              Not supported
> Firefox (Gecko)     19.0 (19)
> Internet Explorer   Not supported
> Opera               Not supported
> Safari              Not supported
> ```

You need to use a regular expression or indexOf.

```
if (indexItem.indexOf(substringText)!==-1) {
```